# Update Column corresponding to the other column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am facing a problem in SQL Server where my query is

```
CREATE TABLE BookRecord
(
     BookId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     BookUsed INT
)

INSERT INTO BookRecord 
VALUES (1), (1), (0), (0), (1), (1), (0), (1)

ALTER TABLE BookRecord 
    ADD KeepTime INT

DECLARE @time INT = 0

UPDATE book1 
SET @time = KeepTime = CASE
                          WHEN book1.BookUsed = 1 
                             THEN 
                                CASE 
                                   WHEN book2.BookUsed IS NULL OR 
                                        book2.BookUsed = 0 
                                      THEN @time + 1 
                                      ELSE @time 
                                END 
                             ELSE 0 
                       END
FROM
    BookRecord book1 
LEFT JOIN 
    BookRecord book2 ON book1.BookId - 1 = book2.BookId

SELECT * 
FROM BookRecord
```

This will generate the output like this

[image]

But I just want that if 1st 1 in BookUsed detects then the variable increments and remain till the last 1.

If it detects 0 then it again fed 0 to the KeepTIme corresponding that record

The Exact output that I want is

[image]

And all will be in single update query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your SQL server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just missing the some lines. When you are updating your variable through case that a time the case also returns "0" and again your variable starts from "0". That's why your column value always returns and display "1".

Use this update query instead of yours

```
UPDATE book1 SET @time = CASE
                          WHEN book1.BookUsed = 1 AND (book2.BookUsed IS NULL OR book2.BookUsed = 0)
                             THEN 
                               @time + 1 
                             ELSE @time 
                          END,
                 KeepTime = CASE
                             WHEN book1.BookUsed = 1 
                               THEN 
                                 @time 
                               ELSE 0 
                             END
FROM
    BookRecord book1 
LEFT JOIN 
    BookRecord book2 ON book1.BookId - 1 = book2.BookId
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a Trigger if yes try this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BookUsedTrigger
 ON BookRecord 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    Update BookRecord set BookRecord.KeepTime = BookRecord.KeepTime +1 from inserted i inner join deleted d on i.BookId = d. BookId where i.BookUsed = 1 and d.BookUsed = 0 and BookRecord.BookId = i.BookId
GO
```

after executed this trigger you can just update the BookUsed flag

```
UPDATE BookRecord SET BookUsed = 1 WHERE --some condition
```

if it turn BookUsed from 0 to 1 it will trigger and Increasing your KeepTime

In case you can't use any trigger i'm afraid that you need to check in update like this

```
UPDATE BookRecord
SET BookUsed = 1,
    KeepTime =  CASE  
    WHEN BookUsed = 0 THEN KeepTime + 1
    ELSE KeepTime
    END 
WHERE -- your conditions
```

But be aware don't put CASE in other Update script than Update that change BookUsed to 1 Or you want only single update for any case use this

```
UPDATE BookRecord
SET BookUsed = @flag,
    KeepTime =  CASE  
    WHEN BookUsed = 0 and @flag = 1 THEN KeepTime + 1
    ELSE KeepTime
    END 
WHERE -- your conditions
```

@flag is your parameter or just replace it with value but i recommend send parameter to query than concatenate it directly

Comment: No i don't want to increase at every execution.
I just want Whenever it detects first 1 from starting or after 0 the it increments.
If it detects 1 after than 1 the variable value should be same.

Comment: Did you mean you want KeepTime to increase every time BookUsed turn from 0 to 1 Or you want to increase KeepTime then change BookUsed to 0

Comment: Yes every time only it increase when BookUsed turn from o to 1

Answer (score 1):

Use `recursive CTE` for SQL server 2008. i used `row_number` in first CTE just to be sure that there will not be gaps

```
with cte as (
    select
        Bookid, BookUsed, rn = row_number() over (order by BookId)
    from 
        BookRecord
)
, rcte as (
    select
        rn, Bookid, BookUsed
        , KeepTime = BookUsed, cnt = BookUsed
    from
        cte
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select
        c.rn, c.BookId, c.BookUsed
        , case
            when c.BookUsed = 0 then 0
            else        
                r.cnt + case when r.BookUsed = 0 and c.BookUsed = 1 then 1 else 0 end
        end
        , r.cnt + case when r.BookUsed = 0 and c.BookUsed = 1 then 1 else 0 end
    from
        rcte r
        join cte c on r.rn + 1 = c.rn
)

update b
set b.KeepTime = r.KeepTime
from
    BookRecord b
    join rcte r on b.BookId = r.BookId

select * from BookRecord
```

Output

```
BookId   BookUsed   KeepTime
-----------------------------
1        1          1
2        1          1
3        0          0
4        0          0
5        1          2
6        1          2
7        0          0
8        1          3
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your solution. But I just want to know Without CTE it is possible or not. Because I want to update in simple way without CTE

Comment: Do you wanna do it without CTE or recursion? You can replace recursion with several self joins, but it will be harder to achieve

Comment: Yes I Want do it without CTE.

Comment: Please guide me how to do it with self join.?

Comment: I guess that will be long and ugly query. Can you explain why don't you want to use CTE

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` function here :

```
select Bookid, Bookused, (case when Bookused = 0 then 0
                               when (Bookid - Seq) > 0 then (Bookid - Seq)
                          else 1 end) as KeepTime
from (select *,
              row_number() over (partition by BookUsed order by Bookid) Seq
      from BookRecord  b
     ) t
order by Bookid;
```

You can take advantage of your *identity* column (`Bookid`) to generate new departmental (`BookUsed`)  sequence and use difference of them as (`Bookid - Seq`) as `KeepTime`.